# Scala: Getting the index of an element in a Map

Tags: scala, dictionary, indexing, data-retrieval

I have a `Map[String, Object]`, where the key is an ID. That ID is now referenced within another object and I have to know what index (what position in the Map) that ID has. I can't believe there isn't an `.indexOf`
How can I accomplish that?

Do I really have to build myself a list with all the keys or another Map with ID1 -> 1, ID2 -> 2,...  ?
I have to get the ID's indexes multiple times. Would a `List` or that Map be more efficient?

Comment: Maps are not ordered (in general); elements in a map do not have an index. That's why there is no `indexOf`. Can you explain what problem you are actually trying to solve by knowing this?

Comment: @Jesper that's what I thought, but there is a `zipWithIndex` on Map... which kind of implies there is an index... I have no idea where that "index" comes from however or if it's what @Dora actually wants

Comment: @Hamish You make a good point, and the existence of `zipWithIndex` on sets (and therefore on maps) has been a subject of [discussion during the planning of Scala 2.13](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/818). As Martin put it: "[...] `zip` is debatable. On the other hand, `zip` is useful. What's to object against `set.zipWithIndex` as a way to arbitrarily assign set elements unique indices?"

Comment: `zipWithIndex` is different stuff.. It creates new `Map` where key is pair of previous `key->value` and new value is zip index.. @Dora is trying to solve different problem.

Comment: When I just use `zipWithIndex` I will get `Map[(String, Object),Int)]` and I don't get an ID's index this way. So I guess building another Map[String, Int] with  ID1 -> 1, ID2 -> 2,... is the best solution?

Comment: @Dora there is no guarantee that the next time you iterate the `Map` each of the elements will have the same index. So it's not a good idea to rely on this. Also there's no way to lookup an element by index in a `Map`, so it's not very useful. Please explain why you need this.

Comment: @Mr.V. & Dora exactly - all I was trying to say here was there is a way to get *some kind of index* (which I'm sure we could easily hack into a solution), but I have no idea if it will give consistent results or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dora, as everyone mentioned, maps are unordered so there is no way to index them in place and store id with them. 
It's hard to guess use case of storing (K,V) pairs in map and then getting unique id for every K. So, these are few suggestions based on my understanding - 
 
 1. You could use **LinkedHashMap** instead of Map which will maintain the insertion order so you will get stable iteration. Get KeysIterator on this map and convert it into a list which give you an unique index for every key in you map. Something like this-

```
import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap
val myMap = LinkedHashMap("a"->11,  "b"->22, "c"->33)
val l = myMap.keysIterator.toList
l.indexOf("a") //get index of key a
myMap.+=("d"->44) //insert new element 
val l = myMap.keysIterator.toList
l.indexOf("a") //index of a still remains 0 due to linkedHashMap
l.indexOf("d") //get index of newly inserted element.
```

Obviously, it is expensive to insert elements in linkedHashMap compared to HashMaps. 
Deleting element from Map would automatically shift indexes to left.

```
myMap.-=("b")
val l = myMap.keysIterator.toList
l.indexOf("c") // Index of "c" moves from 2 to 1.
```

2. Change you map (K->V) to (K->(index, v)) and generate index manually while inserting new elements.

   ```
   class ValueObject(val index: Int, val value: Int)
   val myMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, ValueObject]()
   myMap.+=("a"-> new ValueObject(myMap.size+1, 11))
   myMap("a").index<br/> // get index of key a
   myMap.+=("b"-> new ValueObject(myMap.size+1, 22))
   myMap.+=("c"-> new ValueObject(myMap.size+1, 33))
   myMap("c").index<br/> // get index of key c
   myMap("b").index<br/> // get index of key b
   ```

deletion would be expensive if we need indexes with no gaps, as we need to update all keys accordingly. However, keys insertion and search will be faster.

This problem can be solved efficiently if we know exactly what you need so please explain if above solutions doesn't work for you !!! (May be you really don't need map for solving your problem)

Comment: I am parsing some data and build my objects along the way. Those I store in a map to retrieve later. Some objects are referenced from other objects via ID, so I still need the ID. But I don't have to delete or modify the map once I'm done, so your suggestion of  (K->(index, v)) sounds most reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Maps do not have indexes, by definition.

What you can do is **enumerate** the keys in a map, but this is **not guaranteed to be stable/repeatable**. Add a new element, and it may change the numbers of every other element randomly due to rehashing. If you want a stable mapping of key to index (or the opposite), you will have to store this mapping somewhere, e.g. by serializing the map into a list.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `Map[A,B]` to an ordered collection namely for instance `Seq[(A,B)]` equipped with `indexOf` method. Note for

```
val m = Map("a" -> "x", "b" -> "y")
```

that

```
m.toSeq
Seq[(String, String)] = ArrayBuffer((a,x), (b,y))
```

From the extensive discussions above note this conversion does not guarantee any specific ordering in the resulting ordered collection. This collection can be sorted as necessary.

Alternatively you can index the set of keys in the map, namely for instance,

```
val idxm = for ( ((k,v),i) <- m.zipWithIndex ) yield ((k,i),v)
Map[(String, Int),String] = Map((a,0) -> x, (b,1) -> y)
```

where an equivalent to `indexOf` would be for example

```
idxm.find { case ((_,i),v) => i == 1 }
Option[((String, Int), String)] = Some(((b,1),y))
```